# How to make Entityframework Core set the right Parameter Data Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a User Model with this property defined:

```
[Column("custnmbr", TypeName = "char(15)")]
[StringLength(15)]
public string Custnmbr { get; set; }
```

I reference this in a query:

```
.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = {user.Custnmbr}")
```

But when Entityframework Core `Interpolates` my parameter, it sets the Data Type to `@p0 AS nvarchar(4000)`. That causes `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` in my query plan:

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nchar(15),[C].[CUSTNMBR],0)=[@p0]) may affect "SeekPlan" in query plan choice

My questions are: Should I be worried about this and if yes, How do I fix it?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron MS Sql Server 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try switching to `FromSqlRaw` and creating `SqlParameter` with explicit type. Something like this:

```cs
var p1 = new SqlParameter("@Custnmbr", SqlDbType.Char, 15);
p1.Value = user.Custnmbr;
(...)
.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = @Custnmbr", p1);
```